# what is the xml tag for "sign up for price alert", "add to wish list" and "share"?

Tags: magento-1.9

What are the xml tags for the following links on the product page?
sign up for price alert, add to wish list and share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have installed some custom theme

if you want to know xml tag from any of the template you can know from  to enable template path hints from magento.

To do this go to `System -> Configuration` In the top left there is a box named `“Current Configuration Scope:` “

which has a drop down. 
From that drop down, choose your store view name. By default it is last option in the drop down

i.e Default Store View option. After this go to `Advanced -> Developer->Debug` And here make Template Path `Hints = Yes` - [See more](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-template-path-hints-magento/#sthash.w56RDjzW.dpuf])

you can see template which are using in theme and fine same template in xml files of your theme.

you can use their name in local.xml to remove from specific page of from whole site.